# Dissemination of Calculus in China

Tags: mathematics, terminology, calculus, ancient-china

Much has already been written about the dissemination of Euclidean geometry into China: https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-euclid-in-china, https://academic.oup.com/book/12776/chapter-abstract/162933660?redirectedFrom=fulltext (as well as some commentary on why it was decided to be called "几何": https://hinative.com/questions/22525779, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B9%BE%E4%BD%95)

I am interested in knowing the history of how (Newton's/Leibniz's) calculus was brought to China, and in particular where now-standard terminology like

- calculus https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BE%AE%E7%A7%AF%E5%88%86%E5%AD%A6 (with "微" referring to the "differential" half of calculus, and "积" referring to the "integral" half of calculus)
- derivative https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%E5%AF%BC%E6%95%B0, and differentiation "求导"

first arose.